# POSTing from jQuery to MVC Spring Server responses HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, jquery, spring, post, httpresponse

I am trying to make a POST updating an String Array, using jQuery. The server is a boot Spring MVC Server. When I do the POST, the response from the server is `HTTP 403 Forbidden`.

Spring **Controller**

> ```
>   @RequestMapping(value="getlistmap", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>     public @ResponseBody String getListMapfromOneProject(HttpServletResponse response, Principal p,@RequestBody String respostas) throws IOException {
>     System.out.println("A AJAX call has been detected!");
>     return "ok!";
> }
> ```

**POST** code:

> ```
> var respostas=["hello","hi","bye"];
>   var urlprova = 'getlistmap';
>   $.ajax({
>     type: 'POST',
>     url: urlprova,
>     dataType: 'json',
>     data: JSON.stringify(respostas),
>     success: function (data) {
>         alert("updated successfully");
>       },
>     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
>         alert(err.status);
>         alert('Cannot update, ' + err.responseText);
>     }
> ```
>
> });

**Console** from Server (the URL and method Controller seems to be mapped correctly):

> 2014-11-20 18:44:53.427 INFO 6724 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler] 2014-11-20 18:44:53.466 INFO 6724 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView palmaslab.mapas.controller.myController.login() **2014-11-20 18:44:53.466 INFO 6724 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/getlistmap],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String palmaslab.mapas.controller.myController.getListMapfromOneProject(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.security.Principal,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException** 2014-11-20 18:44:53.467 INFO 6724 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/addProjectPostoSaude],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView palmaslab.mapas.controller.myController.addProject()

Comment: Are you using Spring Security? If so, refer my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34319194/583237).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ajax post does contain the sessionId or user credentials. - When you use Spring Security, then you need to send them with every request.

Comment: Sorry I am learning jquery right now, please could you explain me how i have to send the user credentials? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433351/jsessionid-httponly-cookie-not-sent-to-web-service-from-javascript

Comment: How could I catch the Cookie from a previous getJSON i did before?

Comment: First check your none JSON Requests that they have have that cookie. - And I have not enought Jquery knowlege to answer this - I posted this answer, because I know how spring security works, and I have noticed that your request does not contain any jsession id

Answer (score 0):

Looks legit in general, try following, one of them might solve your problem :

- Adding a slash to your request mapping value :
  `@RequestMapping(value="/getlistmap"...`
- Adding : `contentType: 'application/json'`, to your ajax call
- Describing headers in your request mapping as : `headers =
  {"Content-type=application/json"}`